# Update/Modify variable in ejs page

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a ejs page using node where I want to update my variable. The problem is that it is a part of a multipage view.

I'm passing a user variable from the node server to the webpage.

Once on the page, I have a header. I show the name in the header, but in the body, I update the data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="KBase" ng-init= "m_user=<%=JSON.stringify(user)%>">
 <head>
<title>Index</title>
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
   </head>
  <body ng-controller="accountController">
     <header>
        <% include header %>
     </header>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="accountController as up" ng-init="up.m_user = m_user">
```

I'm using angular to update the data. It is going to the server and updating. However, would rather not update the entire page and I don't want to hae multiple headers. However, the multiple headers is the only way I can see fixing the issue.

My header.ejs

```
          <% if (user){ %>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
        <!--<li><a href="#">Link</a></li> -->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><%=(user.displayName)%><span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/login">logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="/account">account settings</a></li>
           <!-- <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li> --!>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```